# SSRS, changing report in ReportViewer after clicking the button

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have finished the short course from Microsoft about creating Web App with reports from SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) (create-drillthrough-rdlc-report-with-parameters-reportviewer)

During the course, i have created report, that allows drillthrough operation and links another Report (with another Dataset). That work's fine but for my purposes I need more control about the process, that's why I have created buttons to perform the same operation.  Buttons are for retrieving new values from DB and showing results in current `ReportViewer` First button is performing data retrieving for the same report (*Report1*) and dataset (*DataSet1*) like parent report. Second one is retrieving data for another report (*Report2*) and dataset (*DataSet2*).

Code is almost the same, which was executed during standard drillthrough operation from tutorial, but hitting second button (*toReport2*) does not showing any reuslts. I don't know what is wrong here. 
I have checked the datatables results - the are existing and match the datasets.
Going through of similar posts in WEB was not really helpfull. Please help me to resolve this.

```
protected void DataSet1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ReportViewer1.Reset();
    this.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

    DataTable dt1 = getDataSet1Data();
    ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt1);
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = (@"...mypath...\MyApp7\Report1.rdlc");

    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    this.ReportViewer1.Visible = true;

}

protected void DataSet2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ReportViewer1.Reset();
    this.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

    DataTable dt2 = getDataSet2Data();
    ReportDataSource datasource2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dt2);
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource2);
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = (@"...mypath...\MyApp7\Report2.rdlc");

    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    this.ReportViewer1.Visible = true;

}

public DataTable getDataSet1Data()
{
    string constring = "Data Source = x.x.x.x; Initial Catalog = Adventureworks2014; Integrated Security = SSPI";
    using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        string commandText = "SELECT ProductID, Name, ProductNumber, MakeFlag, FinishedGoodsFlag, Color, SafetyStockLevel, ReorderPoint, StandardCost, ListPrice, Size, SizeUnitMeasureCode, WeightUnitMeasureCode, Weight, DaysToManufacture, ProductLine, Class, Style, ProductSubcategoryID, ProductModelID, SellStartDate, SellEndDate, DiscontinuedDate, rowguid, ModifiedDate FROM Production.Product";
        using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlconn))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sqladap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm))
            {
                using (DataSet1 dset1 = new DataSet1())
                {
                    sqladap.Fill(dset1, dset1.Product.TableName);
                    return dset1.Product;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public DataTable getDataSet2Data()
{
    string constring = "Data Source = x.x.x.x; Initial Catalog = Adventureworks2014; Integrated Security = SSPI";
    using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        string commandText = "SELECT PurchaseOrderID, PurchaseOrderDetailID, OrderQty, ProductID, ReceivedQty, RejectedQty, StockedQty FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail";
        using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlconn))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sqladap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm))
            {
                using (DataSet2 dset2 = new DataSet2())
                {
                    sqladap.Fill(dset2, dset2.PurchaseOrderDetail.TableName);
                    return dset2.PurchaseOrderDetail;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Results from DataSet1Button_Click
[image: Results from DataSet1Button_Click]

Results from DataSet2Button_Click
[image: Results from DataSet2Button_Click]

Comment: I don't find anything strange in code. does it works if you click toReport2 before toReport1? does it works if you click toReport1 twice?

Comment: That's was you have written is not a sollution at all, but by saying, that code is fine i realized I am looking in bad area. I needed to change perameter settings. Thank's tezzo for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, solved!
Comment from https://stackoverflow.com/users/2400834/tezzo was helpfull. Code is fine. The problem was in Report2 settings, according which, addtional drillthrough parameter was expected. I have delete it and its working now.
Problem seems to be silly but i my opinion, Microsoft should implement some notification for such cases.

[bugfix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szl0u.png)